# I accidentally selected the wrong bounty reason. How do I fix it?

Tags: feature-request, support, bounties, bounty-remarks, active-bounties

I posted a bounty on my question, [How to access default  KmlLayer in Google Maps JavaScript API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086504/how-to-access-default-kmllayer-in-google-maps-javascript-api-v3), and I accidentally clicked the wrong bounty reason.  Unfortunately, this one doesn't make any sense.  I meant to select that it hasn't received enough attention because there are no answers, but I accidentally posted that "one or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty".  This is clearly problematic, but I don't see any option to fix it

Comment: See this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111967/161808

Comment: yeah ... no way in the system to amend it ... I will see if we can add a 5 minute grace like you have for commenting

Comment: For reference: [a separate request for a grace period](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111967/add-a-grace-period-for-bounty-removal-reversal) of the sort @waffles brought up.

Answer (score 1):

Bounties are designed to be an irreversible journey down one way street. Once added, they're final - you should be extremely careful when selecting the bounty amount and reason. You should be equally sure when awarding the bounty.

Moderators do have the ability to remove and refund a bounty at their discretion. However, it's extremely unlikely that one would elect to do so in these cases - there's simply no guarantee that the user would place the bounty again if refunded. We avoid short circuiting the system, barring *compelling* or extraordinary circumstances.

There's really not much you can do if this happens. Feel free to flag, but realize that the chances of us taking action aren't good. A [grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111967/50049) could be an answer to this, but the idea hasn't received much attention.

Comment: This reasoning is nonsensical. The request is to be able to edit the bounty notice, not revoke the bounty altogether. It’s not like the poster can get the bounty back when the criteria are amended. The bounty poster is free to change their mind about what kind of answer they are looking for anyway.